# iOS crop one part of UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I’m using Avfoundation to capture video and I would like to crop one part of the captured UIImage.
I’m using two UIImageView.
[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikgXt.png)

Here is my code to create the view.

```
    -(void)addCamToView
    {
      AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc]init];
      session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;

       AVCaptureDevice *device =
      [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
      AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput        deviceInputWithDevice:device error:nil];

    [session addInput:input];
   AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    _stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc]init];
    [session addOutput:output];
    [session addOutput:_stillImageOutput];
    output.videoSettings =
    @{ (NSString *)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey :  @(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA) };
   AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
    previewLayer.frame = _imv1.bounds;
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResize;

    CALayer *ca_imv2 = _imv2.layer;
    CALayer *ca_mainImv = _imv1.layer;

    [previewLayer addSublayer:ca_mainImv];
    [previewLayer addSublayer:ca_imv2];

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];

    [session startRunning];
}
```

When user press the capture button I’m running this code to capture the image :

```
    -(void) Capture: (UIImageView *) 
    {
        AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
        for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in _stillImageOutput.connections)
        {
            for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts])
            {
                if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] )
                {
                    videoConnection = connection;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (videoConnection) { break; }
        }
        [_stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer,NSError *error)
             {
                 NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
                 UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

                 UIImage *croppedImv = [self crop:imv2.frame: image];

                 self.imv1.image = croppedImv;
             }];
}
```

Here is my code to crop the image. I would like to extract the part of the image in UIImageView2

```
- (UIImage *)crop:(CGRect)rect :(UIImage *)img {

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(img.CGImage, rect);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:img.scale orientation: img.imageOrientation];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return result;
}
```

For some reason the cropped image is never the image in  UIImageView2.  Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me see if I got this.
You want to display your image in a big image view, then you want to cut a part of that image and show it in a sort of loupe.
At moment you are seeing a different rect of your big image inside the image view 2, is that correct?
I guess that the problem is due to image view 1 content mode (and or image view content mode.

> An image view uses its contentMode property and the configuration of
>   the image itself to determine how to display the image. It is best to
>   specify images whose dimensions match the dimensions of the image view
>   exactly, but image views can scale your images to fit all or some of
>   the available space. If the size of the image view itself changes, it
>   automatically scales the image as needed.

Another issue can be the frame that you are using to crop the image, this is because a view frame represents the coordinate of a view respect its superview.
In your case, that match can be correct only if image view 1 occupy all the bounds of its superview and share the same superview with image view 2.

Comment: Thanks andrea for your answer. It's exactly what i'm trying to do. My final goal is make some operation on the captured image in imageView2. I’m showing it in imageView1 just to be sure that I cropped the right section. The Imageview1 is the parent of the imageView2 and imageView1 is a subView of the main UIView and has the same frame as the main UIView. How can i get the right coordinate of the UIimageView2 to be able to crop the image ?

Comment: Adding a subview to uiimageview is not possible in interface builder only in code. Are you creating your interface in interface builder or code?

Comment: I'm creating the interface in the code behind. I changed the code to add the imv2 in the previewLayer like this :                                        CALayer *ca_imv2 = _imv2.layer;
CALayer *ca_imv1= _imv1.layer;

[previewLayer addSublayer:ca_imv1];
[previewLayer addSublayer:ca_imv2]; and i have the same issue you were right the problem is the bound probably because if i add :   _imv2.center = _imv1.center; the imv2 is not on the center of imv1 but i don't understand what i'm doing wrong i think i'm missing something. Thanks

Comment: Why are you messing around with layers? use just views

Comment: I have the same issue using views and fixed position.     CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imageToCrop.CGImage, rect);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:imageToCrop.scale orientation: imageToCrop.imageOrientation];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);  The returned image is always different than the image in the square